# Removing ViewController from navigation stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I do it with code:

```
NSArray *viewControllersFromStack = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSMutableArray *viewControllersFromStackMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:viewControllersFromStack];
NSMutableArray *viewControllersToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (UIViewController *currentVC in viewControllersFromStack)
{
    if ([currentVC isKindOfClass:[TalksViewController class]])
    {
        [viewControllersToRemove addObject:currentVC];
        if (viewControllersToRemove.count == 2)
        {
            UIViewController *oneVCtoRemove = [viewControllersToRemove objectAtIndex:0];
            [viewControllersFromStackMutable removeObject:oneVCtoRemove];
            [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllersFromStackMutable];

        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that I have reference to removed VC's in navigation Item. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to remove a view from the navigation stack you can simply just call this method on the navigation bar to pop the view from the stack:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To pop an external view use

```
for(UIViewController *currentVC in viewControllersFromStack)
{
    if([currentVC isKindOfClass:[TalksViewController class]])
    {
        [currentVC.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I don't fully understand the question, if you could give just a little more detail?

Comment: Can you tell the world how you fixed it in case anybody else has the same issue? :-)

Comment: This code pops the _top_ view controller in the stack, and so if the view controller of class TalksViewController is not at the top, it will pop the wrong view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct.

I have 'A' as rootview controller. 'B to F' are other view controllers. From 'F', if I wanted to go directly to 'A', it is as under.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

BUT if I wanted to jump to 'B' then the code in answer is helpful. I only changed the array of view controllers to run reverse with 'reverseObjectEnumerator' and Animated to NO with 'popViewControllerAnimated:NO'. the Code is as under

```
NSArray *viewControllersFromStack = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
for(UIViewController *currentVC in [viewControllersFromStack reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    if(![currentVC isKindOfClass:[A class]] && ![currentVC isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        [currentVC.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```